# Is it possible to define functions under stdClass

Tags: php, function, object, stdclass

Here i tried to define a function under stdClass object.

```
<?php
$x= function($name){return "Hello ".$name;};

echo $x("Sun");

$hey = (object)[ "x" => function($name){return "Hello ".$name;}, "y" =>"Hello Venus"];

echo $hey->x("Mercury");
echo $hey->y;
```

But it says: Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::x()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the closest you can get:

```
$x = function ($name) { return 'hello ' . $name; };
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->x = $x;

echo call_user_func($obj->x, 'john'); // this will work
echo $obj->x('john');                 // this will not work
```

You won't need to use call_user_func with php7 though.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show why call_user_func() is used.